# Contact form redirect delay

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, delay, contact-form-7

I am working on a WordPress website `contact form`. Where I would like to `redirect` the page after the user press the send button and also a `5-sec delay`.

The following code works fine with the `redirecting` but I also would like to wait `5 sec` before the redirecting.

```
  <script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
      location = 'https://www.inext.se/career/';
    }, 5000 );
    </script>
```

Do anyone knows what I am doing wrong here and why it is `redirecting` perfectly but not `delaying 5 sec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect a user after a certain period use a [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
document.addEventListener("wpcf7mailsent", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = 'https://www.inext.se/career/'
  }, 5000);
});
```